# Using ng-table in AngularJS Material

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I want to use this table in my material design angularjs app: http://ng-table.com/#/

The problem is it requires bootstrap. It probably isn't a good idea to have two CSS frameworks.

Is it possible to somehow extract the needed CSS for the ng-table and to isolate it to an id? So it won't effect anything else in my app.

It's very sad no one has made a decent table for material (md-table isn't enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Here the CSS code used by the library:

```
.ng-table th {
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
.ng-table th.sortable {
    cursor: pointer
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator {
    padding-right: 18px;
    position: relative
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:after,
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before {
    content: "";
    border-width: 0 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    visibility: visible;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .3;
    margin-top: -4px
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before {
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #000
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:hover:after,
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc {
    background-color: rgba(141, 192, 219, .25);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .75)
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:after,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after {
    margin-top: -2px
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:before,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:before {
    visibility: hidden
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:after,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:hover:after,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after {
    visibility: visible;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -khtml-opacity: .6;
    -moz-opacity: .6;
    opacity: .6
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    box-shadow: none
}
.ng-table th.filter .input-filter {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-header th {
    text-align: left
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-selector {
    display: block
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-close,
.ng-table .ng-table-group-toggle {
    float: right
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-toggle {
    margin-right: 5px
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .ng-table-responsive {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999
    }
    .ng-table-responsive tr {
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        border-left: 1px solid #999;
        border-right: 1px solid #999
    }
    .ng-table-responsive td:before {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 8px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 50%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 700
    }
    .ng-table-responsive thead tr th {
        text-align: left
    }
    .ng-table-responsive thead tr.ng-table-filters th {
        padding: 0
    }
    .ng-table-responsive thead tr.ng-table-filters th form>div {
        padding: 8px
    }
    .ng-table-responsive td {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
        white-space: normal;
        text-align: left
    }
    .ng-table-responsive td:before {
        content: attr(data-title-text)
    }
    .ng-table-responsive,
    .ng-table-responsive tbody,
    .ng-table-responsive td,
    .ng-table-responsive th,
    .ng-table-responsive thead,
    .ng-table-responsive tr {
        display: block
    }
}
.ng-table-pagination {
    margin-top: 0
}
.filter:after,
.filter:before,
.ng-table-group-selector:after,
.ng-table-group-selector:before {
    display: table;
    content: " "
}
.filter:after,
.ng-table-group-selector:after {
    clear: both
}
.filter>.filter-cell {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.filter-horizontal>.filter-cell {
    padding: 0 2px
}
.filter-horizontal>.filter-cell:first-child {
    padding-left: 0
}
.filter-horizontal>.filter-cell.last,
.filter-horizontal>.filter-cell:last-child {
    padding-right: 0
}
.s12 {
    width: 100%
}
.s11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%
}
.s10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%
}
.s9 {
    width: 75%
}
.s8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%
}
.s7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%
}
.s6 {
    width: 50%
}
.s5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%
}
.s4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%
}
.s3 {
    width: 25%
}
.s2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%
}
.s1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%
}
@media all and (max-width: 468px) {
    .s1,
    .s2,
    .s3,
    .s4,
    .s5,
    .s6,
    .s7,
    .s8,
    .s9,
    .s10,
    .s11,
    .s12 {
        width: 100%
    }
    .filter>.filter-cell {
        padding: 0
    }
}
```

Put a custom class when you include your HTML of the table (like for example: `my-ng-table`) and find and replace inside the CSS code above all the occurrences of `.ng-table` with `my-ng-table`.

Then all the block of codes where you see `.s1` `.s2` etc, transform them in `my-ng-table .s1` etc etc (in order to ensure that this will affect only the classes inside your table.

You may need to wrap in the same way also the classes `filter`, but I don't think it will create any conflict if you leave it in that way.

And it should work just for your tables without any conflict.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thats only the css for ng-table. Ng-table also need bootstrap.

Comment: The only bootstrap classes needed seem to be: `btn-group`, `pagination` and `form-control`. It seems no more than these. Simply copy the bootstrap CSS source of these elements from the developers tab, and import just this code inside your CSS